# how to read a file in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to read a text file like `test.txt`:

```
birthbook(tom,9,1).
birthbook(add,9,1).
birthbook(ddd,8,1).
```

Code:

```
test:-
  open('test.txt', read, Str),
  read_file(Str,Lines),
  close(Str),
  write(Lines), nl.

read_file(Stream,[]) :-
  at_end_of_stream(Stream).
read_file(Stream,[X|L]) :-
  \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
  read(Stream,X),
  read_file(Stream,L).
```

However, it shows that 
ERROR: test.txt:1:4: Syntax error: Unexpected end of file.

Answer (score 2):

as an example of controlling Prolog peculiar execution flow, consider how to turn read/2, a non backtrackable builtin, into one suitable for findall/3:

```
read_one_term(S, B) :-
    repeat,
    read(S, B),
    ( B = end_of_file, !, fail ; true ).

?- open('book.pl', read, S), findall(B, read_one_term(S, B), L), close(S).
S = <stream>(0x7f51b00b3340),
L = [birthbook(tom, 9, 1), birthbook(add, 9, 1), birthbook(ddd, 8, 1)].
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues I see with your implementation. First, the `at_end_of_stream/1` succeeds only *after* an attempt was already made to read past the last line in the file. It does not tell you whether you are *about to read* past the end. So your predicate is going to do the stream read *after* the last line is read, instantiating `X` with `end_of_file` before `at_end_of_stream/1` succeeds. (This is similar to the behavior of the `feof(.)` function in the standard C library, which the veteran C programmers will tell you to avoid using.)

The second issue is you don't take care of the case when `at_end_of_stream/1` does succeed.

You can refactor your code as follows:

```
read_file(Stream, Lines) :-
    read(Stream, Line),               % Attempt a read Line from the stream
    (  at_end_of_stream(Stream)       % If we're at the end of the stream then...
    -> Lines = []                     % ...lines read is empty
    ;  Lines = [Line|NewLines],       % Otherwise, Lines is Line followed by
       read_file(Stream, NewLines)    %   a read of the rest of the file
    ).
```

A quick test yields:

```
?- open('test.txt', read, Str), read_file(Str, Lines), close(Str), write(Lines), nl.
Str = <stream>(0x871c410),
Lines = [birthbook(tom, 9, 1), birthbook(add, 9, 1), birthbook(ddd, 8, 1)].

?-
```