# How to read a file and assert facts in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a file `test.txt`:

```
:-dynamic birth/3.
birth(tom,1,1).
birth(tonny,1,1).
```

How can I read the file and assert them into prolog. 
Say only

```
birth(tom,1,1).
birth(tonny,1,1).
```

assert into prolog and I can use them as facts.

Comment: why not `?- [your_file]`.

Answer (score 0):

assert/3 could do the job:

`assert(birth(Name,X,Y)).`

This could help you aswell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37574687/6350977